# Moving a computer with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$target = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter "OU=Sales - Clothes,OU=Mall,OU=Computers,OU=Site2364"
get-adcomputer computername1 | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $target.DistinguishedName
```

My OU has a space (Sales - Clothes)

The error that appears says

```
Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide 
an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:2 char:53
+ ... mputer PCJ21584 | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $target.DistinguishedName
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Command 
   s.MoveADObject
```

Comment: I just figured it out. I needed to use -Identity instead of -LDAPFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -Identity instead of LDAPFilter to get the intended results

```
$target = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity"OU=Sales - Clothes,OU=Mall,OU=Computers,OU=Site2364"
get-adcomputer computername1 | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $target.DistinguishedName
```

Answer (score 0):

`LDAPFilter` probably isn't the parameter you want. If you know the name of the organizational unit, you can use `Filter` to find by name, i.e.:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -like "Sales - Clothes"}
```

Or you can use the CmdLet piped to the `Where-Object` CmdLet:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | `
    Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -match "OU=Sales - Clothes,OU=Mall,OU=Computers"}
```

Comment: If there is another Site (like Site2244) that contains the same containers, how will I know which one it will end up in? OU=Sales - Clothes,OU=Mall,OU=Computers,OU=Site2244

Comment: @softwareisfun in that case you would use `-SearchBase` to only look in one container